# How to resolve AdView nullpointerexception errors

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, google-play, admob

I have updated the Google Play Services library to the latest version. 5.0.8.9, and I followed the instructions on Google's Developer site for creating an AdMob Banner ad.

However, when I run the app, I get a java nullpointerexception when the AdView view is being inflated by the Activity Manager.

It doesn't matter if I create the AdView in the XML or at runtime in the java code.

Here's my activity's OnResume code, where the error happens.

```
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        final int connectionStatusCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

        if (connectionStatusCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.bannerAdView);

            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest
                .Builder()
                .build();

            adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        }
  }// end onResume
```

My activity's XML code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/yourbasiclayout"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
    >
        <TextView android:id="@+id/myAdView_Label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="Google Ads"/>

        <com.google.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/bannerAdView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            ads:adUnitId="MyBannerAdId"
            ads:adSize="BANNER" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have still the legacy Admob view element in the xml:

```
 <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/bannerAdView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        ads:adUnitId="MyBannerAdId"
        ads:adSize="BANNER" />
```

Replace it with the google play admob (Note the `com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView`):

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
   android:id="@+id/bannerAdView"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="10dp"
   ads:adUnitId="MyBannerAdId"
   ads:adSize="BANNER"/>
```

Also check your Activity code that you import Google Play AdView and not the legacy one.

see the guide here:
https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/play-migration

Comment: Thanks man! I had found a post earlier saying to check my imports in the Java file to make sure I was using the Google play services libraries.  But I hadn't thought to check the XML element's source. The answers to problems sometimes seem so simple and obvious when it's known where to look...

Answer (score 2):

You are using the deprecated API (`<com.google.ads.AdView`) in your layout xml file. Change:

```
 <com.google.ads.AdView 
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adUnitId="MyId"
        ads:adSize="BANNER" />
```

to:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adUnitId="MY_AD_UNIT_ID"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"/>
```

Make sure you import the right classes too:

```
import com.google.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.ads.AdView;
```

instead of:

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
```

You can follow the official guide on migrating to the new admob [here](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/play-migration).

Comment: nice answer, but 4 mins late ;-)

Comment: yes, thanks Nana, if you were first, I would have selected your answer. Donfuxx was first, and his answer was exactly what I had been searching for.

Comment: No problem. What matters most is getting your problem solved :)